# how can i fix this weird thumbnails bug? i tried clearing cache and changing wallpapers nothing worked

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, thumbnails

here in the settings menu, it shows like this even though I have a working background on the desktop

[image]

and same with virtual desktops only the one I'm using shows the background. others show this big Windows photo's app icon

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted recently? Not shutdown, instead of power down and back up do a proper restart from the power menu.

Comment: i did restart after clearing cache couple times

Comment: It could be a bug. Not sure if this will force it to work but try typing "appearance" in the start menu search and a result should pop up "adjust the appearance and performance of windows". Click on that, and in the resulting window select the "adjust for best appearance" option. Now reboot your computer. I don't know if this will fix the problem, as I have no way of testing it here, but if it works i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: still no changes